# telnet issue :Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 11211: Connect failed

Tags: connection, port, telnet

while Am trying to use following command

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

am getting this error

```
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 11211:
Connect failed
```

I enabled telnet.How can i overcome this error?

Comment: `enabled telnet` just means the default telnet port 23. Port 11211 is normally used by `memcached`, is that running?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Telnet.

Answer (score 3):

You should check your firewall settings (iptables --list as root or sudo for Linux), and see if there's anything possible blocking that. Check which ports are open (netstat -nl --inet) and also check running processes and find the process that you expect to be listening.

Whatever you expect to be listening on that port is probably not running, or is misconfigured.